# android RadioRealButton: How to implement complex layout?

Tags: android, radio-button

I need a RadioRealButtonGROUP (library: https://github.com/ceryle/RadioRealButton) 
with three buttons in the first row and two in the second.
How would I implement this?
If I put a LinearLayout inside of the RadioRealButton, the buttons stop being clickable.

Answer (score -1):

Why would you put a LinearLayout inside it? I think you should wrap the Buttons in a LinearLayout instead

Edit:

You can use RadioRealButtonGroup to group buttons, here you are a sample code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<!-- First Row -->
    <co.ceryle.radiorealbutton.RadioRealButtonGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioRealButtonGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:rrbg_animateDrawables_enter="overshoot"
        app:rrbg_animateTexts_enter="overshoot"
        app:rrbg_dividerColor="@android:color/black"
        app:rrbg_dividerSize="1dp"
        app:rrbg_radius="10dp"
        app:rrbg_selectorColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:rrbg_selectorSize="6dp">

        <co.ceryle.radiorealbutton.RadioRealButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:rrb_drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:rrb_drawableHeight="36dp"
            app:rrb_drawablePadding="8dp"
            app:rrb_drawableWidth="36dp"
            app:rrb_ripple="true"
            app:rrb_rippleColor="@android:color/black"
            app:rrb_text="Button 1"
            app:rrb_textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <co.ceryle.radiorealbutton.RadioRealButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:rrb_drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:rrb_drawableGravity="right"
            app:rrb_drawableHeight="36dp"
            app:rrb_drawablePadding="8dp"
            app:rrb_drawableWidth="36dp"
            app:rrb_ripple="true"
            app:rrb_rippleColor="@android:color/black"
            app:rrb_text="Button 2"
            app:rrb_textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <co.ceryle.radiorealbutton.RadioRealButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:rrb_drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:rrb_drawableGravity="right"
            app:rrb_drawableHeight="36dp"
            app:rrb_drawablePadding="8dp"
            app:rrb_drawableWidth="36dp"
            app:rrb_ripple="true"
            app:rrb_rippleColor="@android:color/black"
            app:rrb_text="Button 2"
            app:rrb_textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </co.ceryle.radiorealbutton.RadioRealButtonGroup>

    <!-- Second Row -->
    <co.ceryle.radiorealbutton.RadioRealButtonGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioRealButtonGroup"
        app:rrbg_animateDrawables_enter="overshoot"
        app:rrbg_animateTexts_enter="overshoot"
        app:rrbg_dividerColor="@android:color/black"
        app:rrbg_dividerSize="1dp"
        app:rrbg_radius="10dp"
        app:rrbg_selectorColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:rrbg_selectorSize="6dp">

        <co.ceryle.radiorealbutton.RadioRealButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:rrb_drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:rrb_drawableHeight="36dp"
            app:rrb_drawablePadding="8dp"
            app:rrb_drawableWidth="36dp"
            app:rrb_ripple="true"
            app:rrb_rippleColor="@android:color/black"
            app:rrb_text="Button 1"
            app:rrb_textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <co.ceryle.radiorealbutton.RadioRealButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:rrb_drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:rrb_drawableGravity="right"
            app:rrb_drawableHeight="36dp"
            app:rrb_drawablePadding="8dp"
            app:rrb_drawableWidth="36dp"
            app:rrb_ripple="true"
            app:rrb_rippleColor="@android:color/black"
            app:rrb_text="Button 2"
            app:rrb_textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </co.ceryle.radiorealbutton.RadioRealButtonGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

If this solved your question please mark this answer

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. You jsut defined 2 RadioRealButtonGroups. That's - obviously - not the same as having one RadioRealButtonGroup. I need the behaviour of 1 Group. Like only 1 element selected and such.